# VB | Loading SQL Query into Combobox

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I am trying to fill a combobox with a SQL Result
I think my problem is handling the data in the datatable form.

```
    Dim sql As String
    Dim sqlquery As String
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Control;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass"
    sqlquery = "Select dbName from Databases"

    Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        connection.Open()
        Using conn As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn)
            Dim rs As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
            dt.Load(cmboxDatabaseName)
        End Using 'comm
    End Using 'conn
```

When I run the program I just stare at a sad empty combobox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost right, but you need to Load the datatable using the DataReader.
Then assing the DataTable to the DataSource of the Combo

```
Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    connection.Open()
    Using comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection)
            Dim rs As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
            dt.Load(rs)
            ' as an example set the ValueMember and DisplayMember'
            ' to two columns of the returned table'
            cmboxDatabaseName.ValueMember = "IDCustomer"
            cmboxDatabaseName.DisplayMember = "Name"
            cmboxDatabaseName.DataSource = dt
    End Using 'comm
End Using 'conn
```

Also you could set the combobox `ValueMember` property to the name of the column that you will use as key for future processing and the `DisplayMember` property to the column name that you want to display as text to choose from for your user

Comment: I moved this code to be button click event drive.
At least its blowing up now LOL
ConnectionString = "ConnectionString = Data ... noticed that right off the bat.

Changed to 
ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Control;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass"

Now says
Connection *** Highlighted

ConnectionString = "ConnectionString = Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Control;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass"

is my conenctionsting wrong?

Comment: Hope none has been injured :-)  Could you tell me the error message?

Comment: lol we jsut lost a few support people no biggy
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Think Ive got some conns and comms mixed up as well

Comment: Did you install SqlExpress on your dev PC? If yes then the `DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS` should be used instead of `(local)`

Comment: I had to just fix my Connection stream

Comment: Only problem... It populates the ComboBox with 9 Instances of "System.Data.DataRowView"
I have 9 databases on my dev box ... so thats good!

Comment: The items displayed by the combobox are obtained calling the ToString() method of the object passed to the DataSource. In case of a DataTable the object used is the DefaultView property of the DataTable where each item is a DataRowView and calling ToString() on a DataRowView produce the name of the class. You need to set the DisplayMember and the ValueMember as explained in my example (of course use your own column names)

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it as

```vb
Dim Con = New SqlConnection(_ConnectionString)
Dim cmdAs New SqlCommand
Dim dr As New SqlDataReader

    Try
        If Con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            Con.Open()

            cmd.Connection = Con
            cmd.CommandText = "Select field1, field2 from table"


            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            ' Fill a combo box with the datareader
            Do While dr.Read = True
                ComboBoxName.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0))
                ComboBoxName.Items.Add(dr.GetString(1))
            Loop

            Con.Close()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

Hope it works for you.