# Insert data from multiple tables with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I want to insert data from one table and another table with just one button.

Here are my tables:

user table:

```
id      course_id      firstname      middlename      lastname
1       1              foo            bar             foos
2       1              fooos          bars            fooss
3       2              ipsum          fooss           lorem
```

course table:

```
id      course_name
1       BSIT
2       Computer Science
```

Both id's in user and course table are auto increment. Now I want to insert data. Sample: firstname=foo, middlename=bar, lastname=bar, course=BSIT. As you can see I want to type a course connected to the user. Now the problem is I want to insert the foreign key automatically so that they will be connected.

My query to output the two tables is:

```
SELECT user.id, user.firstname, user.middlename, user.lastname, course.course_name 
FROM course INNER JOIN user ON course.id = user.course_id
```

Here is my current code for inserting data:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO user(firstname, middlename, lastname) VALUES(?fname, ?lname, ?mname)"

    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?fname", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?lname", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?mname", TextBox3.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?course", TextBox4.Text)
```

I am stuck here. That's why I did not include the course table because I don't know what to do. Please help me.

Comment: How do you let your user choose the couse name? Do you have some kind of DropDownList or ComboBox filled with courses? If yes you need to attach to this combo also the course id needed when you insert the user record

Comment: they just type the course.

Comment: if i will choose ComboBox or DropDownList, how should I code this can you show me?

Comment: In that case you need a query to retrieve the ID of the course typed by your user before trying to insert. Better use a DropDownList or a ComboBox depending on your app kind. Is this a web app or a desktop one? ASP.NET or WPF?

Comment: can you show me? this is just vb.net

Comment: Numerous ways of doing this -eg  you can use a dataset which will do it automatically for you, or you can use @@IDENTITY in your SQL to retrieve the new PK in the parent table and then build this into your INSERT for the child table.

Comment: @peterG can you show me how? the @@IDENTITY

Comment: @Rak [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql) is pretty clear

Comment: @peterG ... OP tagged MySQL and you show a SQL Server link. As a general-purpose language, VB can connect to any major RDBMS. Just because MSSQL and VB are MS products don't mean they are married at the hip!

Comment: @Parfait Ooops you are right! I missed that tag! It appears that MySQL [has a similar feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html) though.

Comment: You have a string variable sql, its inserting values in the database. What you can do is when the insert is finished you can use the same sql string variable again and assign it a new query with an insert query for another table this way you can easily duplicate the value of the course and add it to the other table.
If this this problem is not solved yet give me a reply and I will create a code for you which will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As @Steve mentions, consider a [ComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx) object (assuming Windows forms) which you can populate with a database query as the DataSource which @Steve's own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16971553/1422451) shows.

From there, in your SQL statement insert the [`comboBox1.SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) with other columns. And usually, for predetermined lists, you do not let the user type in an open-ended textbox a string like *course name* as misspellings and inconsistencies will not align to actual values:

```vb
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO `user` (firstname, middlename, lastname, course_id) VALUES (?fname, ?lname, ?mname, ?course)"

cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?fname", TextBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?lname", TextBox2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?mname", TextBox3.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?course", ComboBox.SelectedValue)
```

---

An alternative method using existing setup of *course name* textbox would be the `INSERT INTO...SELECT` query which again is not reliable since user can potentially misspell, add special characters, even include white spaces to values. And below assumes *course_name* is unique.

```sql
INSERT INTO `user` (firstname, middlename, lastname, course_id)
SELECT ?fname, ?lname, ?mname, c.course_id
FROM course c
WHERE c.course_name = ?course
```